# how to map face contours points on real time face, which we get from Firebase MLKit for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-mlkit

how to map 2D Vision points array to create face map after getting vision points from faceDetector ??

```
faceDetector.process(visionImage) { features, error in

    guard error == nil, let features = features, !features.isEmpty else {
        return
    }
    for face in faces {
        let frame = face.frame
        if let leftEyeContour = face.contour(ofType: .leftEye) {
            // 2D vision Points array
            let leftEyePoints = leftEyeContour.points
        }
        if let upperLipBottomContour = face.contour(ofType: .upperLipBottom) {
            let upperLipBottomPoints = upperLipBottomContour.points
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this you posting to show how it is done or are you having issues with your code?

Comment: Try this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-ios/index.html), it has a good example